Using ltrace, where is the call to malloc/new?
Consider the following straightforward piece of code (coliru link):
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string buf(1024, 'a');
    std::cout << buf << '\0';
    return 0;
}

If I compile and execute it with g++ -O0 main.cpp && ltrace -n3 -fS ./a.out, and inspect the output:
[pid 25689] SYS_mprotect(0x7f02e5293000, 4096, 1, 0x7f02e5294030) = 0
[pid 25689] SYS_brk(0, 0x7f02e46d3b20, 0x7f02e46d3b78, 0x7f02e46d3b78) = 0xb00000
[pid 25689] SYS_brk(0xb33000, 0x7f02e46d3b20, 0xb00000, 0x7f02e46d3b78) = 0xb33000
[pid 25689] __libc_start_main(0x400a22, 1, 0x7ffeeb3a1338, 0x400b80 <unfinished ...>
[pid 25689]    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_local_data()(0x7ffeeb3a1210, 1024, 97, 0x7ffeeb3a1237) = 0x7ffeeb3a1220
[pid 25689]    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider::_Alloc_hider(char*, std::allocator<char> const&)(0x7ffeeb3a1210, 0x7ffeeb3a1220, 0x7ffeeb3a1237, 0x7ffeeb3a1220) = 0x7ffeeb3a1237
[pid 25689]    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct(unsigned long, char)(0x7ffeeb3a1210, 1024, 97, 1024) = 1024
[pid 25689]    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)(0x6012c0, 0x7ffeeb3a1210, 0xb12400, 0xb12400 <unfinished ...>
[pid 25689]       SYS_fstat(1, 0x7ffeeb3a1040, 0x7ffeeb3a1040, 1) = 0
[pid 25689]    <... std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) resumed> ) = 0x6012c0
[pid 25689]    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char)(0x6012c0, 0, 0x7f02e5064310, 0) = 0x6012c0
[pid 25689]    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()(0x7ffeeb3a1210, 0x7f02e46d5780, 0x7f02e5064310, 0xb12831) = 1
[pid 25689]    SYS_write(1, 0xb12430, 1025, 88aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)  = 1025
[pid 25689]    SYS_exit_group(0, 60, 0, 2956 <no return ...>
[pid 25689] +++ exited (status 0) +++

Where is the call to malloc and/or new to allocate the 1KB of chars? I suspected that it was omitted because it happened inside another library call (the _M_construct), but that assumption is wrong; I see library calls inside other library calls. So, where is malloc/new? I expected to see a call to malloc/new inside the std::string constructor.
NOTE: I'm aware that string uses short buffer optimizations, but the local capacity of a default constructed std::string in gcc is 15 (std::string str; std::cout << str.capacity() << '\n';), which is well below 1KB of chars. So the 1KB of 'a's must be placed on the heap.

Memory for a standard string is allocated using operator new. It's unspecified whether that operator calls malloc. Not really an answer though since it doesn't explain why operator new doesn't appear in your output.

If there is one, it should be somewhere inside std::allocator. A name like _Alloc_hider would be a primary suspect for perhaps hiding the call.

The code has been optimized into a bunch of SYS_ function calls. The allocation is totally omitted. There's a SYS_write with a long immediate string literal input.

malloc is just a C wrapper around system call and has nothing to do with C++ unless you call it directly (and C++ version, the std::malloc can be inlined). Built-in new isn't a function. Red.Wave is correct there.

@Swift-FridayPie That's why I'm using ltrace, to inspect all library calls. Malloc is not a syscall, and syscalls don't call malloc. Malloc is a library function and the kernel won't do calls to userland library function, that makes no sense. Not sure about how new interacts with malloc though.

The simple answer is that ltrace is not showing everything. In gdb I can clearly see #0 operator new #1 std::basic_string::_M_construct ...

@KamilCuk Yes that could probably explain it, but I wonder, why isn't ltrace able to find it? I guess it might be related with symbol resolution. If I'm not wrong ltrace detects library calls by interfering with the symbol resolution process. If operator new and malloc are both "solved" even before ltrace can operate, that might explain it. I would like to understand that process a bit better, to understand when ltrace could "fail", and so when I can rely on it.

I have no idea "why". I managed to see them with ltrace -x '+@.*'. I know nothing about ltrace.

@ABu Use the -x option, as this answer states, and the output here shows the call to malloc.

Where is the call to malloc and/or new to allocate the 1KB of chars? -- malloc@libc.so.6(1025, 0x7ffdcfc70678, 0, 0x3fffffffffffffff) = 0x1e5b020 when -x is used.  Probably this should be closed as a duplicate.

By default ltrace only traces library calls from your a.out. They're all calls into libstdc++.so'. mallocandfreeare not called bya.outbut bylibstdc++.sointolibc.so. To search for them exhaustively make that explicit with: g++ -O0 main.cpp && ltrace -e malloc+free -n3 ./a.out 1> /dev/null. Output: libstdc++.so.6->malloc(1025) = 0x573fc9fd02b0\nlibstdc++.so.6->free(0x573fc9fd02b0) = `
